# Modify previous commit without modifying working directory

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

```
      D  
     /  
A-B-C-E
```

Branch D is my current working directory, however, I want to 'clone' C again, make some changes and commit them to create E without having to change anything I did in D. Then I can continue to develop on D. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the previous commit (state), C:

```
git checkout HEAD^
```

Don't worry about the "detached HEAD" message. Work work work, commit the changes needed to get E, then

```
git checkout -b branch-E
```

then `branch-E` contains E and its history. Now checkout the branch you were originally in to get to state D again.

I've shown it for getting to the previous commit, denoted `HEAD^`, but you can checkout any commit in your repo by giving its "[treeish](http://book.git-scm.com/4_git_treeishes.html)", e.g. its SHA1 value.

Comment: Don't forget to stash local changes first, if any.

Comment: @Ryan: right, and make sure the original commit is actually in the history of some branch.